# dot net gridview sorting problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, sorting

I have a web application (with C#). I have a GridView and want to be able to sort its contents. I have added the tags

...

```
AllowSorting="True"
onsorting="MyGridView_Sorting">
```

and

```
asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="NAME"
```

inside the GridView. I have implemented the MyGridView_Sorting method. Thing is: it does not work. Does nothing. The header text "Name" looks like an active link, but clicking produces no effect. Putting a break point inside

```
MyGridView_Sorting
```

shows that it actually never goes inside the function. What is wrong? What do I miss?

Thanks!!!

Sep

```
< asp:GridView ID="MyGridView"
runat="server"                               
CssClass="pvgrid" 
Width="90%" 
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
OnRowCommand="MyGridView_RowCommand"
AllowPaging="True" 
PageSize="10" 
AllowSorting="True"
onsorting="MyGridView_Sorting" 
onpageindexchanging="MyGridView_PageIndexChanging" >

< Columns >
< asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="NAME"  />
< /Columns >
< /asp:GridView >


protected void MyGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    MyGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    MyGridView.DataBind();
}

protected void MyGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dataTable = MyGridView.DataSource as DataTable;

    if (dataTable != null)
    {
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " "+ ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);
        MyGridView.DataSource = dataView;
        MyGridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**GridView delegates sorting to underlying DataSource.** GridView does not perform sorting on its own, it just delegates. So you need to look into your DataSource for sorting. What is the DataSource ? What kind of Data does it display ? Are those custom objects coming from `ObjectDataSource` or you're using `SqlDataSource` or `LinqDataSource` ?

Comment: I populate the data source with a custom function that interrogates the database and binds a dataset to the gridview. What I do not understand is why the application does not even get inside my sorting function. Not even the first line. The function is not called at all. I am sure I am not understanding properly the logic of this business...

Comment: the editor does not like "<", ">"
how do I put the code inside my post?

Comment: what I would like to understand first is why clicking on the bound field with a sort expression does not make the application call the sorting method